# It is good to have one realm across application?

Tags: android, realm

I would like to know is it good practice to use only one realm instance across application? (Dagger @Singleton) or does it has some kind flaws/drawbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both yes and no. Having one instance if fine, however Realms are thread confined which means that a true singleton (as the one provided by Dagger) will not work.

If you instead inject a thread local singleton it should work. That would however be be something you created yourself inside Daggers `provide` methods as Dagger doesn't give you this out of the box as far as I know.

It would probably be easier to inject a new instance and remember to close it when done with it.

Comment: Thank you, Realm ftw :)!

Comment: Hi Christian, is there any good example you know of Dagger with Realm? I injected in my project, and I put an abstract `closeRealm()` method to my `BaseActivity` so other activities would have to override it and close the instance. However, it didn't seem a clean solution to me. If you know a solution where I can get realm instance and close in one place, that would be great solution.